# NIFI: Extract particular value from JSON array using EvaluateJsonPath Processor?

Tags: json, apache-nifi

I have the following [JSON structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMu2o.png) and I would like to extract the `3` from the value from context containing `All UpdateCounter's`. The following is what I have tried and it didn't work:

```
$.counters.aggregateSnapshot.counters.[context=="All UpdateCounter\'s"].valueCount
```

What could be the possible NIFI expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1 - SplitJson 
- on $.Conters
2 - EvaluateJsonPath**

$.id

$.context

$.name

$.valueCount

$.value

**3 - RouteonAttribute**

route rule:

**${context:contains('All UpdateCounter\'s')}**

or

**${context:equals('All UpdateCounter\'s')}**

**4 - extract Text  - if you want it like a csv**

${id},${context},${name},${valueCount},${value}

Answer (score 2):

Even though this is an old question, future readers could benefit: what about [JoltTransformJSON](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.JoltTransformJSON/)? It uses only one processor and returns what you need:

**Jolt Transformation DSL: Shift**

**Jolt Specification**:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "counters": {
        "aggregateSnapshot": {
          "counters": {
            "*": {
              "*": {
                "context": {
                  "All UpdateCounter's": {
                    "@3": "results"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Result:

```
{
  "results" : {
    "9" : {
      "id" : "xxxxxxx",
      "context" : "All UpdateCounter's",
      "name" : "flag",
      "valueCount" : 3,
      "value" : "3"
    }
  }
}
```

Tested using: [Jolt Transform Demo](https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#andrewkcarter2) with these settings (the web app won't let me permalink the example, so here's an image):

[image]